# Solving equation involving complex conjugates

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

I've trying to solve this equation:
$$z^2+2\bar{z}^2+z-\bar{z}+9=0$$
In order to do so, I've substituted $z$ with $z=x+iy$, where $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. Then:
$$(3x^2+y^2)+i(2y-2xy)=-9$$
So:
$$
\begin{cases}
3x^2+y^2=-9 \\
2y-2xy=0 \\
\end{cases}
$$
But the first equation can't be solved unless $x,y\in \mathbb{C}$.

I don`t see where I'm making the mistake.

Comment: If $ z=x+iy $ then $ z^2= x^2 -y^2 +2ixy$

Comment: You should get $3x^2-3y^2$

Answer (score 3):

We have:
$$z^2+2\bar{z}^2+z-\bar{z}+9=0\Rightarrow\\\bar{z}^2+2z^2+\bar{z}-z+9=0\Rightarrow$$
(by subtracting the two relations)
$$-z^2+\bar{z}^2+2z-2\bar{z}=0\Rightarrow\\(\bar{z}+z)(\bar{z}-z)-2(\bar{z}-z)=0\Rightarrow\\(\bar{z}-z)(\bar{z}+z-2)=0\Rightarrow\\\Im(z)=0 \\\text{or}\\\Re(z)=1$$

First case $(\Im(z)=0)$ is easily discarded and the second gives us $z=1+2i$ or $z=1-2i$

Comment: @dxiv Yes, thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if $z=x+yi$, then$$z^2+2\overline z^2+z-\overline z+9=3x^2-3y^2+9+2(y-xy)i.$$So, the system that you should solve is
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}3x^2-3y^2=-9\\y=xy.\end{array}\right.
$$
Its solutions are $(x,y)=(1,-2)$ and $(x,y)=(1,2)$. That is, the solutions of the original equation are $1\pm2i$.

Comment: Bruh,  I'm dumb. Thank you so much!